# JsSIP play remote audio

Tags: javascript, sip, jssip

I am using jsSIP with Asterisk in my project. The proplem is I don't jnow how to play audio answer from Asterisk in my browser. Now I am trying this

```
myPhone.on('newRTCSession', function(data){
    var session = data.session;
        session.on('peerconnection', function(e){
            remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
            remoteAudio.play();
        });
    });
```

but event is not fired, also i tried event "addstream", but as i understood it is removed in my current JsSIP version (3.2.4)

connecting to Asterisk is fine. I start call, receive answer, then Asterisk must play audio file, and terminate call. And it is terminated after 8 seconds from connecting, but audio is not playing.
Here is the answer in `RTCSession.connection.remoteDescription.sdp`

```
v=0
o=- 857805013 857805013 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 19006 RTP/SAVPF 0 8 126
c=IN IP4 95.47.143.134
a=rtcp:19007 IN IP4 95.47.143.134
a=candidate:Hc0a80068 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.0.104 19006 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:S5f2f8f86 1 udp 1694498815 95.47.143.134 19006 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.104 rport 19006 generation 0
a=candidate:Hc0a80068 2 udp 2130706430 192.168.0.104 19007 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:S5f2f8f86 2 udp 1694498814 95.47.143.134 19007 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.104 rport 19007 generation 0
a=ice-ufrag:218863545319313f5ed15c9b0503a7f1
a=ice-pwd:5e1dc0457efadffe13b44666585eecb9
a=fingerprint:sha-256 56:EE:4C:B8:78:88:AB:A4:C2:72:84:94:15:BE:7C:6E:D4:BD:2F:21:F1:F6:6D:68:E8:91:14:DC:94:72:75:0C
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:150
a=ptime:20
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an attribute called `connection` which contains `RTCPeerConnection` instance in `RTCSession` instances. As far as I understood, it represents the remote/other part.

So here is a code sample which shows how to add an event listener to catch the media stream of the remote part and use it.

```
session.connection.addEventListener('addstream', function (e) {
  // set remote audio stream
  const remoteAudio = document.createElement('audio');
  remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
  remoteAudio.play();
});
```

For incoming calls, `session.connection` is not instantly instantiated. So you will need to attach another event listener, `peerconnection`, to catch that as you mentioned in your question. Including that part, it should look as below;

```
session.on('peerconnection', function(data) {
  data.peerconnection.addEventListener('addstream', function (e) {
    // set remote audio stream
    const remoteAudio = document.createElement('audio');
    remoteAudio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
    remoteAudio.play();
  });
});
```

Here are some links which may help you understand it better;

1. [JsSIP.RTCSession.connection](http://jssip.net/documentation/3.2.x/api/session/#attribute_connection)
2. [RTCPeerConnection.onaddstream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onaddstream)

Comment: I use simple  `remoteAudio.srcObject = e.stream`, and it help me

Answer (score 0):

The `addstream` event is now deprecated. You should instead use the `track` event. Example implementation:

```js
attachRemoteStream(session) {
  // Fetch the existing audio element or create a new one
  const remoteAudio = document.getElementById('remoteAudio')

  session.connection.ontrack = (event) => {
    if (event.track.kind === 'audio') {
      if (event.streams.length > 0) {
        remoteAudio.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      } else {
        const stream = new MediaStream([event.track]);
        remoteAudio.srcObject = stream;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

And then for incoming calls, call the function on `peerconnection`:

```
session.on('peerconnection', (e) => {
  attachRemoteStream(session);
});
```